# How to test a Service Layer in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a web application with three layers: Web > Services > Core.  I've just added a Services.Tests unit tests project and I'm trying to figure out how to get started.

I've added a reference from the Services.Tests project to the Services project.  I then created an instance of the Services.service class in my Test class:

```
[TestClass]
public class CrudTests
{
    private readonly SetServices _setService = new SetServices();

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
```

But I got an error about `_setService` needing a reference to my Core project.

**First question:** Why do I need to reference my core project if the Services project already references it?

I've added the reference and ran the empty test, which passed.  I then tried to call one of the basic methods within my service class:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod()
{
    _setService.CreateSet("Test Set", "Test Set Details", null);
```

But I get a `providerIncompatileException`.

**Second question:** What is the recommended way to create/use a dedicated test database?

**Third question:** How do I tell my tests project which database to use?

Comment: In the future, try to split unrelated questions into different posts (you got at least 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By parts,

> Why do I need to reference my core project if the Services project already references it?

Project references aren't inheritable, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13472189/1250033). The fact that `Services` has a dependency on `Core` does not imply that whoever consumes `Services` needs to know anything about `Core`, or for that matter uses any logic exclusively defined in `Core`.

> What is the recommended way to create/use a dedicated test database?

It depends entirely on what database, what ORM, what framework, etc. There aren't fixed ways to do it.

> How do I tell my tests project which database to use?

In the same way you tell the application to do it: through the configuration. Simply create a `DatabaseStub` and hard-code the test database information in it.

Comment: Thanks, yet again, for the help :)