# C# Constructor breaks due to another constructor

Tags: c#, class, object, constructor

I have a C# point class with multiple constructors in a library (This is a different class than a System.Drawing.Point in .NET).

```
Public class Point {

   public float X;
   public float Y;
   public float Z;

   //Constructor 1
   public Point(float x, float y, float z) {
      this.X = x;
      this.Y = y;
      this.Z = z;
   }
   //Constructor 2
   public Point(Point point) {
      this.X = point.X;
      this.Y = point.Y;
      this.Z = point.Z;
   }
   //Constructor 3
   public Point(PointF point) {
      this.X = point.X;
      this.Y = point.Y;
      this.Z = 0;
   }
   //Constructor 4
   public Point(System.Drawing.Point point) {
      this.X = point.X;
      this.Y = point.Y;
      this.Z = 0;
   }
}
```

When I am trying to create a new `Point` object using the constructor that takes in `float` as parameters, everything works fine. When I want to create a new `Point` using an existing `Point` object (Constructor 2), I receive an error saying that I need to reference the `System.Drawing` assembly. I am guessing this is because of constructors 3 and 4 since they take a `System.Drawing.Point` and a `PointF` as an argument, but I don't see why they should pose an issue, since the constructor I am trying to use is completely unrelated to them, and constructor 1 works fine when called. How do I get around this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Add a reference to System.Drawing?

Comment: You can't initialize one instance member using an other instance member

Comment: @Polyfun This object is in a library, and I don't want to require users to implement System.Drawing unnecessarily.

Comment: @Jordan1993 What do you mean by that? In constructor 2 I am able to use the X, Y and Z values of the `Point` parameter to create a new `Point` with the same X, Y and Z values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround for this, if you can accept it.

Add the following to your `Point` class:

```
public static Point Clone(Point p)
{
    return new Point(p);
}
```

Then in the code that is currently failing to compile, do this instead:

```
Point p = new Point(0, 0, 0);
Point q = Point.Clone(p);
```

(Of course, you don't have to call the method `Clone()` - call it `Copy` or `CopyCtor` or whatever you like.)

As to *why* the compiler insists that you must include a reference to an assembly defining types that you're not even using, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18219497/106159).

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210729/why-do-i-sometimes-have-to-reference-assemblies-referenced-by-the-assembly-i-r).